# How to update sqlite database from server

Tags: android, sqlite, rest

I want to update `sqlite` database in Android from a remote server.

What are the various ways to implement this?

Can I send db from server to mobile or send a `json`, so I can parse and update in the mobile?

Comment: I think that the best way to do that by using [Sync Adapter](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html)

Comment: Assuming you want to install Couchbase on the remote Server (you mentioned JSON, so that would be a good idea). You can use [Couchbase Lite](http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/couchbase-mobile) instead of SQLite